# How should I create an email with attachments (MIME) for Amazon Simple Email Service using force.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, apex-code, amazon-ses

I would like to create emails with attachments via force.com through [Amazon Web Services' Simple Email Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Resources.html) service because of the force.com organization-wide limit of 1,000 single outbound email messages per day.

The `SendEmail` method in AWS' SES does not support attachments, but they do provide support for raw emails via `SendRawEmail` (at least for most file type that you'd be interested in sending).

As far as I can tell, you can't get the raw version of a SingleEmailMessage and need to construct it yourself.

**How should I create a multipart MIME email message in APEX?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [EncodingUtil](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) class to convert the attachment to Base64.

Lay out your email according to the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) standards.

Here's a [borrowed](http://www.akadia.com/services/email_attachments_using_perl.html) example:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_----------=_10167391557129230"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2002 19:32:35 UT
From: martin dot zahn at akadia dot ch
To: martin dot zahn at akadia dot ch
Subject: MIME test
X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 2.106  (B2.11; Q2.03)

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_----------=_10167391557129230
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world!

--_----------=_10167391557129230
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/zip; name="test_file.zip"

UEsDBBQAAAAIAEAUmicKJJts5wUAANkOAAAHAAAAaG93LmNnaa1XbW/bRgz+
7AD5D6ziJPJmR8k+DEj8snWd0wRonS51VwxNYcj22bpZ1qm6cx0v8H77SN5J
APsNAAAAAA==

--_----------=_10167391557129230--

.
```

Comment: I did some searching around to find an MIME writing class in another language that I could port to APEX (it looks simple enough, but I'm new to it and would love to avoid any gotchas), but I didn't see anything obvious. Any that you'd recommend?

Comment: HA! Never mind. The perl example that you provided in the link is perfect.

Comment: That might be worth a shot. If it were me, I'd write the simplest class I could with the single purpose being to create the type of email you need. A general purpose email class would be a lot more work.